# Multiple choice question on a fixed point of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f$ is a continuous mapping from $[0,1]$ to itself which is continuously differentiable in $(0,1)$ and such that $|f^{'}(x)|\leq 1/2 \forall x\in (0,1)$.Then there exists a unique $x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x$

$f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous.So $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f^{'}(x)|(x-y)|\leq1/2|(x-y)|$

How to go from here.Is this the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $[0,1]$ is complete metric space

Show $f$ is a contraction using mean value theorem, and apply [fixed point theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: thanks I have got my answer

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Banach fixed point theorem guarantees existence and uniqueness.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Oh yes... i was thinking too much unnecessarily... :P